# B2C Redirect to specified URI after Login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using b2c for our identity management. We have a destination link that only authorized users can see. Let's call this https://www.hypertrends.com/my-destination

When they arrive at this page, if they are unauthorized, then they get redirected to the B2C Login. This works perfectly fine. However, after login, we would like to send them back to the original page (i.e. my-destination) they first landed on.

We can't seem to figure out how to get that done. Does anyone have an idea on how this can be implemented in B2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the authentication library to pass in a value for the “state” parameter. This parameter will be returned in the authentication response to your application.

Encode a value which represents the location of where the user was on the website, and put it in the “state” parameter.

After the user logs in, have the application parse the state parameter and send the user to the correct location.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/openid-connect#send-authentication-requests